# In which collection object in action script (flex) we can get Tree data coming from java class?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript-2

We want to get **Tree** data from java class in some collection object of action script (flex). which object to use, to store data and how to populate it in Tree like structure?

Below is our custom defined Tree class.

```
public class Tree 
{
    public Node root;

    public static class Node 
    {
        public String file;
        public String fileType;
        public String comments;
        public LinkedList<Node> children;

        public Node(String file, String fileType, String comments) {
            this.file = file;
            this.fileType = fileType;
            this.comments = comments;
            children = new LinkedList<Node>();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What does Java have to do with ActionScript?

Comment: It has a lot to do with it, how exactly does a (meaningful) Flex application get data?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what your project uses as the intermediary layer. You can go the 'manual' route with [RemoteClass] which registers an alias of a front-side Class to a middle-tier representation. This might need some manual massaging with the ByteArray transport for AMF especially if the front-side uses it's own property name access. If the project uses LCDS then this gets a little easier, as collections are typically represented by ArrayList and LCDS converts this automatically.

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a25